# Doors doors doors, c'mon down to the door store!

Tags: code-challenge

### The challenge is twofold:

Make a program that builds a door. *ASCII, HTML or otherwise*

Make the door functional. *Opens and closes*

*Either open-able through input or interaction!*

- Non-functional door +5 points.
- Just a open-able door +10 points.
- Interactive door +15 points.
- Fancy door +20 points. *This means revolving,bifold etc*
- Animated +20 points.
- <100 characters +50 points.
- -100 points for using a program specifically designed for drawing or animation.

If you have criteria suggestions leave them in the comments.

#### Non-functional open door example:

```
<?php
$idiots_in_room=true;

if($idiots_in_room)
{

$count=20;
$count2=7;
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{

if($i==0)
{
echo str_repeat("-",10);
if($i==0){echo ".";}
echo "\n";
}
elseif($i==9)
{
echo str_repeat("-",10);
echo str_repeat("Â ",7)."o"."|";
echo "\n";
}
elseif($i<=9)
{

echo str_repeat("-",1).str_repeat("Â ",8).str_repeat("-",1);

echo ($i<5) ? str_repeat("Â ",$i*2)."\\" : str_repeat("Â ",8)."|";
echo "\n";
}
elseif($i<=14)
{
if($i>9){echo str_repeat("Â ",$i)."\\";}
echo str_repeat("Â ",$count2--)."|";
echo "\n";
}

}
}
```

#### Example Output:

```
----------.
-        -  \
-        -    \
-        -      \
-        -        \
-        -        |
-        -        |
-        -        |
-        -        |
----------       o|
          \       |
           \      |
            \     |
             \    |
              \   |
```

Comment: Do you have any door examples?

Comment: @beary605 Non-functional example provided

Comment: define a "door"

Comment: What about using external files for ASCII code (or images) for the doors? How do they count?

Answer (score 21):

#### JavaScript, 4380 characters, 65(?) points

ASCII? Check. HTML? Check. Is a door? Check. Openable door? Check. Interactive? Check. Fancy? Double doors with properly positioned hinges, I hope that counts. Animated? Check. Under 100 characters? Ha. Not using facilities intended for drawing? Check.

[Live demo.](http://switchb.org/kpreid/2012/door/) (Note: In my testing with Firefox, clicking the doors more than once doesn't work — for some reason the event handler doesn't fire again and I'm baffled as to why; pointing out what I did wrong would be welcome. Though, you might want to run this in Chrome anyway for decent JS performance.)

```
<title>Door</title>
<pre onmouseup="turn();" style="display: table; margin: auto; font-family: 'Monaco', monospace; font-size: 0.6em; line-height: 0.7em;">
</pre>
<p>Click doors to open or close.</p>
<script>

  // Appearance of hit surface - global used to avoid allocating a record to return
  var mat;

  // Scene construction tools
  function box(size,ms) {
    return function (x, y, z) {
      var vdist0 = Math.abs(x) - size[0];
      var vdist1 = Math.abs(y) - size[1];
      var vdist2 = Math.abs(z) - size[2];
      mat = vdist0 > vdist1 && vdist0 > vdist2 ? ms[0] :
            vdist1 > vdist0 && vdist1 > vdist2 ? ms[1] :
            ms[2];
      return Math.max(vdist0, vdist1, vdist2);
    };
  }
  function translate(vec, obj) {
    var dx = vec[0];
    var dy = vec[1];
    var dz = vec[2];
    return function (x, y, z) { return obj(x - dx, y - dy, z - dz); };
  }
  function mirror(obj) {
    return function (x, y, z) { return obj(-x, y, z); };
  }
  function spin(obj) {
    return function (x, y, z) {
      var a = Date.now() / 1000;
      var s = Math.sin(a);
      var c = Math.cos(a);
      return obj(
        x * c + z * s,
        y,
        x * -s + z * c
      );
    };
  }
  function doorturn(obj) {
    return function (x, y, z) {
      var a = pos;
      var s = Math.sin(a);
      var c = Math.cos(a);
      return obj(
        x * c + z * s,
        y,
        x * -s + z * c
      );
    };
  }
  function rotx(a, obj) {
    return function (x, y, z) {
      var s = Math.sin(a);
      var c = Math.cos(a);
      return obj(
        x,
        y * c + z * s,
        y * -s + z * c
      );
    };
  }
  function roty(a, obj) {
    return function (x, y, z) {
      var s = Math.sin(a);
      var c = Math.cos(a);
      return obj(
        x * c + z * s,
        y,
        x * -s + z * c
      );
    };
  }
  function union(as, bs) {
    return function (x, y, z) {
      var a = as(x, y, z); var am = mat;
      var b = bs(x, y, z);
      if (a < b) {
        mat = am;
        return a;
      } else {
        return b;
      }
    };
  }

  // Display parameters
  var vw = 80, vh = 80;
  var timestep = 1/30;

  // Scene
  var wallhwidth = 30;
  var wallhheight = 35;
  var wallmat = [";", "\u2014", ":"];
  var dhwidth = 10;
  var dhheight = 20;
  var hthick = 2;
  var door = translate([-dhwidth*2, 0, 0], doorturn(translate([hthick, 0, dhwidth], box([hthick, dhheight, dhwidth], [".", "\u2014", "|"]))));
  var doors = union(door, mirror(door));
  var wall = union(
    union(
      translate([dhwidth*2+wallhwidth, 0, -hthick], box([wallhwidth, wallhheight, hthick], wallmat)),
      translate([-dhwidth*2-wallhwidth, 0, -hthick], box([wallhwidth, wallhheight, hthick], wallmat))),
    translate([0, wallhheight-(wallhheight-dhheight)/2, -hthick], box([dhwidth*2, (wallhheight-dhheight)/2, hthick], wallmat)));
  var floor = translate([0, -dhheight - 1.1, 0], box([100, 1, 100], ["/","/","/"]));
  var sill = translate([0, -dhheight - 1, -hthick], box([dhwidth*2, 1, hthick], ["\\","%","\\"]));
  var sbox = translate([0, 0, -12], spin(box([8, 8, 8], ["x", "y", "z"])))
  var scene = union(sbox, union(union(wall, doors), union(floor, sill)));
  var view = translate([vw/2, vh/2, -100], rotx(0.2, roty(-0.6, scene)));

  // Animation state
  var pos = -Math.PI/2;
  var dpos = 0;
  var interval;

  // Main loop function
  function r() {
    // Update state
    pos += dpos * timestep;
    if (Math.abs(pos) >= Math.PI/2) {
      dpos = 0;
      pos = Math.PI/2 * pos / Math.abs(pos);
      if (pos < 0) { // no animation needed
        clearInterval(interval); interval = undefined;
      }
    }

    // Render scene
    var t = [];
    for (var y = vh - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
      for (var x = 0; x < vw; x++) {
        var z = 0, distance;
        while ((distance = view(x,y,z)) > 0.12) {
          z -= distance;
          if (!isFinite(z) || z < -1000) {
            mat = " ";
            break;
          }
        }
        t.push(mat);
      }
      t.push("\n");
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].textContent = t.join("");
  }

  // Click handler
  function turn() {
    if (dpos !== 0) {
      dpos *= -1;
    } else {
      dpos = (pos < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 2.3;
    }
    if (!interval) {
      interval = setInterval(r, timestep*1000);
    }
  }

  // Render initial state
  r();
</script>
```

When closed, the doors look like this:

[image: (Screenshot of closed doors.)]

Comment: Gotta admit, thats some beautiful work there.

Comment: That is awesome.

Answer (score 9):

## HTML & CSS3, 55 points

Fancy, interactive, animated door is 55 points, I think.

Yes, this opens like any other door, but if a sliding door counts as fancy, why doesn't a rotating one? If a rotating one isn't fancy, well, a sliding door is no problem `:)`

A demo is available at http://result.dabblet.com/gist/3132160/ac475112dbba493d2dd7d98493d4f4ceaa209a7c. Click the doorknob to open and close. No JavaScript involved; it's just the magic of CSS3.

```css
#wall {
    background-color: #eee;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: rotateX(-10deg);
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#door-container {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}

#door {
    background-color: brown;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    width: 300px;
}

#door .knob {
    background-color: gold;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 20px;
}

#open:target + #wall #door {
    transform: rotateY(-145deg);
}

#open:target + #wall #open-link {
    display: none;
}

#close-link {
    display: none;
}

#open:target + #wall #close-link {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span id="open"></span>
<div id="wall">
    <div id="door-container">
        <div id="door">
            <a href="#open" id="open-link" class="knob"></a>
            <a href="#closed" id="close-link" class="knob"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By Sliding I originally meant "Sliding glass door" like for a patio, but I could see how it wouldn't be considered fancy (especially in coding terms, as its much easier than a rotating). Also, by Rotating door I meant Revolving. Will correct.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica 271 chars

```
Manipulate[a = {0, 0, 0}; b = {0, 0, h}; p = Polygon; c = Cuboid; t = Rotate;Graphics3D[{c@{{-w - 1, 0, 0}, {-w, 1, h}}, c@{{w + 1, 0, 0}, {w, 1, h}},t[p@{a, b, {-w, 0, h}, {-w, 0, 0}}, r, {0, 0, 1}, {- 2 w/3, -w/3, 0}], t[p@{a, b, {w, 0, h}, {w, 0, 0}}, -r, {0, 0, 1}, { 2 w/3, -w/3, 0}]}],{{r, 0}, 0, 3/2}, {{w, 2}, 1, 3}, {{h, 4}, 3, 5}]
```

[image: doors]

The double doors

- open by rotation from zero to 90 degrees (using the slider `r`)
- can be have their height and width set by sliders (`h` and `w`).
- are in a 3D lighting environment
- can be interactively rotated to be viewed from different angles.

---

The code is based on a [program](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/OpeningADoor/) by Sándor Kabal.

Answer (score 4):

## Python - 65 points, 86 chars

Interactive and less than 100 chars.

Waits for input and *shows you the door*.
Valid input is "open" and "close" and "bye".

```
g,s=1,'open close'
while g:
 i=raw_input()
 print '_'+'/_ '[s.find(i)/5]+'_'
 g=i in s
```

Comment: You could probably set it to toggle open/close without typing commands and still meet the requirements--it would save you a few chars.

Comment: Probably, but then again, this isn't code-golf, so it doesn't really matter ;)

Comment: pretty boring looking door, but a great looking mousetrap

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 127 chars

This is a more streamlined implementation than the one I submitted earlier. It has a single door.
The single door

- opens by rotation from zero to 90 degrees (using the slider `o`)
- is in a 3D lighting environment
- can be interactively rotated to be viewed from different angles.

However, it uses a fixed door height and width.

```
Manipulate[a = {0, 0, 0}; Graphics3D[{Tube[{a, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 2}, a}, .03],Rotate[Cuboid@{a, {1, -.1, 2}}, o, {0, 0, 1}, a]}], {o, 0, -Pi/2}]
```

[image: door2]

Comment: You should probably have editted your previous submission, rather than submitting a new one.

Comment: @fireDude67 If this had been a Code Golf challenge, I would have simply replaced my earlier entry with the shorter code. However, the SO indicated interest in both short programs and more complicated programs (doors with more features).

Comment: oh sorry i got confused then

Comment: @fireDude67 No problem.